# Create header file from COM TLB

Tags: c#, .net, c++, visual-studio, com

Given a managed COM object and an associated tlb file, I would like to access it from some unmanaged C++ code WITHOUT using the TLB/import command. But use a header file.

Is there a way to extract a header file from a TLB?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it (on a whim). The OLE/COM Viewer allows you to save a TLB file as a header, C, or IDL file! Very cool! 
Thanks!

Comment: Almost ten years ago, wow. - The Windows 10 oleview.exe lets me export .idl files, but if I select .c or .h, I simply get no output file, no error, nothing. Any idea why that is the case?

Comment: For the creation of .c or .h files certain tools like `midl` or `cl` need to be available on the command line. So for oleview to work correctly, start it from the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

i am unsure why you do not want to use the import command. this will ensure that every time you compile the code you get a header matching the COM library.

otherwise, you risk using an obsolete header in case you forget to manually generate the header.

Comment: Well, I personally found this question (and accepted answer) because I was looking for the same thing because I cross-compile a Windows DLL on Linux using MinGW compiler which doesn't support #import directive